# Can't select text in TouchSwipe jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, swipe

[TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) is a great plugin for adding swipe to your website. But I have an issue on selecting text when the this plugin is activated.

```
     $(window).swipe( {
        //Generic swipe handler for all directions
        swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                dnlShow();
        },
        swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                dnlHide();
        },
        //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
        threshold: 75
      });
```

Any good solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have found two solutions:

1. Add `.noSwipe` class to the content that you want to be selectable. ( in my case it was impossible)
2. Detect the mobile and tablet devices first then activate this plugin so I did this:

   ```
   // Check if you are in mobile or not
   // Code credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery
   function isMobile() {
     try{ document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true; }
     catch(e){ return false; }
   }

   if ( isMobile() == true ) {
       // Swipe plugin for handling touch events
       $(window).swipe( {
       //Generic swipe handler for all directions
       swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
               dnlShow();
       },
       swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
               dnlHide();
       },
       //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
       threshold: 75
     });
   }
   ```

for detecting mobile and tablet devices there are several solutions, you can check at [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

I hope this help others too.

Answer (score 1):

You better attach swipe to touch event, so it also work on PC with touchscreen.
The code looks like :

```
$(document).on("touchstart", function(event) {
    $(window).swipe( {
        swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                dnlShow();
        },
        swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                dnlHide();
        },
        threshold: 75
    });
});
```